# Validation alert: An illegal choice has been detected in a CCK form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I am loading state select option through ajax for the selected country and by default the state option is

> none

with the below reference stackoverflow issue asked few days b4,

how to set multi select CCK Field type for country state city with geoname module?

http://goo.gl/Xpwu0

I couldn't find any answer till now, so tried my own way by

if country selected, based on the country the state have to listed from geoname api so i did it through ajax and appended to the list correspondingly to city.

finally after submitting i got error

> An illegal choice has been detected.
>   Please contact the site administrator.

Answer (score 0):

The form system automatically validates the selected value of a select and only allows those which are defined in '#options'. There is no way around that in D6, in D7, there is a flag to disable that.

You need to use #ahah and rebuild the form on the serverside. The following modules might be useful to you:

- http://drupal.org/project/ahah_helper (for building it yourself)
- http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select (Maybe you can extend that...?)